# unable to install phpmyadmin on rhel6

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, rhel6, epel

I am using RHEL 6.Currently php 5.3.2 is installed.I want to install **phpMyAdmin**  in my system.for that **php5.5** is required.So I am trying to upgrade php version, but it fails because of dependency check.

I installed **remi and epel repo**.
To upgrade php5.3 to php 5.5 ,I used following command

```
yum -y upgrade php*
```

but it failed with the following message ,

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
Error: Package: php-common-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)
Error: Package: php-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)
Error: Package: libzip5-1.5.1-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
Error: Package: php-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)
Error: Package: php-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)
Error: Package: gd-last-2.2.5-5.el6.remi.i686 (remi)
           Requires: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I upgrade my system with php 5.5,so that I can install **phpMyAdmin** on **RHEL6** .please help to resolve this.

Comment: Upgrading software & RPM management isn't a programming problem. Your question is off-topic here and would be better suited to Superuser or a UNIX / Linux / Red Hat specific forum.

Comment: phpMyAdmin in EPEL works with php 5.3.3 in base repostiory

Comment: I have php 5.3. installed,but i am unable to install phpmyadmin. Even when I am trying to update the software (System--> Administration --> Software Update),it failed due to Transaction Error.If I issued yum update command,it also giving me error Error: Package: php-cli-5.6.38-1.el6.remi.i686 (remi-php56)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)...........